# php mail bcc multiple recipients

Tags: php, email, bcc

How do I make a bcc mail?
If I send that mail, It shows me all the recipients!

```
$to=array();
$members_query = mysql_query("select email from members");
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($members_query) )
{
    array_push($to, $row['email']);
}

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
//$headers .= 'To: '.$newName.' <'.$newEmail.'>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: SmsGratisan.com <admin@website.com' . "\r\n";


mail(implode(',', $to), $title, $content, $headers);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add a BCC header with list of recipients. See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for examples.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Set your `mail` to field to `null`, and then implode your `$to` array in your headers

```
$headers .= 'From: SmsGratisan.com <admin@website.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'BCC: '. implode(",", $to) . "\r\n";


mail(null, $title, $content, $headers);
```

Comment: Nice answer, I think you are missing a '>'

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers .= 'Bcc: mail@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score -2):

CC and BCC can be sent as headers (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

You can also use other mail libraries - the PEAR Mail library makes sending emails a little more object-oriented. http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected

Answer (score -3):

Please use pass Just Array instead of doing any kind of Implode, Set quotes, comma etc.

Example:

```
    $bcc = array();

    foreach ($users as $user) 
    {
        $bcc[] = $user['User']['email'];
    }
```

And pass This To `Mail` Function:

```
        $email->from($from)
//            ->to($from)
              ->bcc($bcc)
```

Thanks,
Ankit Patel