# adding multiple blind carbon copy recipients - php wordpress wpmu

Tags: php, wordpress, wpmu

I'm currently using the membership 2 membership software by WPMU. There's an automated message that gets sent to all new members when they successfully register. The message is sent to all the board members. the problem is that it is carbon copied to them and they are listed as recipients. I would like to change that so they are blind carbon copied and the new user is the only listed recipient. this is the code I use for that:

```
<?php
add_filter('ms_model_communication_send_message_recipients', function($recipients){
$otehr_emails = array('treasurer@bwa.org', 'webmaster@bwa.org', 'president@bwa.org', 'membership@bwa.org', 'writers-bwa-owner@yahoogroups.com');
$recipients = array_merge($recipients, $otehr_emails);
return $recipients;
});
```

this code adds those emails as carbon copy recipients. I'd much rather prefer them to be blind carbon copy recipients. the WPMU support board has this as a solution:

```
<?php
function mp_add_bcc_email( $headers, $this, $subscription ) {

    $headers[] .= 'Bcc: yourmail@exmaple.com';

    return $headers;
}

add_filter( 'ms_model_communication_send_message_headers', 'mp_add_bcc_email', 10, 3 );
```

Is there a way to edit the above code to allow for multiple blind carbon copy recipients? if not, is there another php script capable of adding blind carbon copies to the automated email responses in the wmpu membership 2 software?

Thank You!

Comment: Whats a `Blind Carbon Copy` ... lol a `BCC` though I doubt it uses carbon ... ha ha.  You just put them in as a comma seprated list.  ie. `'Bcc: yourmail@exmaple.com, myemail@example.com';`

Comment: or if you want to get fancy, you can do `'Bcc: '.implode(', ', $emails);`  A better question is how do you give that function an array of email addresses.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238207/php-mail-bcc-multiple-recipients

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix wait? when you say 'that question' do you mean with your .implode answer or with the first answer?